# GetUserMedia Callback Undefined

Tags: callback, getusermedia, mediastreamsource

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to make an online audio recorder using the getUserMedia API. The problem that I am having is that whenever I try to call navigator.getUserMedia, I am getting an error that the success callback function is undefined, and therefore not a function. It works when I add parentheses after the callback, but then I get an error about an invalid MediaStream source when I call createMediaStreamSource.

I have found some examples that use getUserMedia online, but I am running into the same problem when I try to run them from my computer, even though they clearly work online.

Here is my code below. Thanks!

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();


//tests if browser is compatible with getUserMedia API
function hasGetUserMedia()
{
return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||      navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}

//successful callback for getUserMedia
function gotStream(stream)
{    
console.log('Compatible')

//set up microphone input to Web Audio API
var mic = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

//connect
mic.connect(filter);
filter.connect(context.destination);

console.log('Here')
}

//error Callback for getUserMedia
function errorCallback()
{
alert('Error capturing audio');
}

//initial function
function testGetUserMedia()
{
if (!hasGetUserMedia())
{
    alert("getUserMedia() is not supported in your browser");
    window.close();
}

//if Compatible
getUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream, errorCallback);

}

window.addEventListener('load', testGetUserMedia);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the code you gave, you are not calling `getUserMedia` on the navigator context (`navigator.getUserMedia`), but on the `this` context. Secondly, calling `navigator.getUserMedia` won't be enough, because that isn't browser-specific. I would recommend returning the actual `getUserMedia` function from `hasGetUserMedia` instead of returning a boolean.

However, when I fixed those two problems, I had no problem with your code. It ran just fine. As a simple test, I just changed:

```
getUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream, errorCallback);
```

to

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream, errorCallback);
```

:: Running on Chrome 37